# Efficient numpy approach to iterate through elements of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

With the following code snippet, I am trying to generate a vector where each element of it is drawn from a different normal distribution. The "mean" and "standard deviation" (arguments to `random.normal`) values for this is obtained from 2 numpy vectors, `meanVect` and `varVect`. Both the vectors have the same `shape` as that of vector to be generated.

I am using list comprehension to achieve the same, which I have used as a quicj and dirty fix to achieve my objective.   Is there a numpy specific approach to achieve the same, which is more efficient than my current solution.

```py
from numpy import random
meanVect = np.random.rand(1,100) # using random vectors for MWE
varVect = np.random.rand(1,100)  # Originally vectors from a different source is used
newVect = [random.normal(meanVect[i],varVect[i]) for i in range(len(meanVects[0])) ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`np.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) takes array-like inputs for `loc` and `scale`, you can just do:

```
newVect = np.random.normal(meanVect, varVect)
```

As long as both input vectors have the same `.shape`, this should work.